# "einander" vs. "sich" vs. "sich gegenseitig/wechselseitig"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „sich“, „sich gegenseitig“ und „einander“? Oder viel mehr: Was ist das Gemeinsame? Wann wird in den folgenden Fällen welches Pronomen verwendet?

> „Sie lieben einander.“ vs. „Sie lieben sich.“ vs. „Sie lieben sich gegenseitig.“
>   „Wir lieben einander.“ vs. „Wir lieben uns.“ vs. „Wir lieben uns gegenseitig“
>   „Ihr verprügelt einander.“ vs. „Ihr verprügelt euch.“ vs. „Ihr verprügelt euch gegenseitig.“

Mich interessieren *grammatikalisch auslegende* Antworten, am besten von Germanisten oder Indogermanisten.

Ich dachte, dass ein Reflexivpronomen fehl am Platz ist, während eine Ergänzung um „gegenseitig“ oder „wechselseitig“ nur eine schlechte Krücke ist und „einander“ das einzig Wahre ist.

Comment: Was meinst du eigentlich mit "grammatikalisch auslegend"? Grammatisch ist jede Form korrekt. Die Frage ist eher, ob eine Nuance geändert wird, die Semantik noch Gültigkeit besitzt oder ob es ein Muttersprachler so sagen würde.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, dass ist eine knifflige Sache, weil man zwischen der reflexiven Version ("sich lieben") und der transitiven Version ("etw. lieben") unterscheiden muss. 
"Sie lieben sich" könnte im richtigen Kontext auch heißen, dass die Personen jeweils sich selbst - nicht jemand anderen - toll finden. Um die Verhältnisse klar zu machen, kann man dass "gegenseitig" noch hinzufügen, was eigentlich das Verb näher bestimmt.
Dagegen benötigt "lieben" als transitives Verb aber immer noch ein Objekt ("einander", "Kuchen", etc.).

Ist aber nur eine Theorie, da ich kein Germanist bin, sondern nur ein Hobbysprachforscher.
Für mich hört sich in allen Fällen die einfache reflexive Variante am besten an, d.h. "Sie lieben sich.", "Wir lieben uns." und "Ihr (ver)prügelt euch."

Comment: *einander* hat für mich einen leicht literarischen Hauch, während *gegenseitig* gänzlich merkwürdig klingt. In diesem Sinne stimme ich dir zu, dass die einfache Variante am besten vom Sprachgefühl ist.

Comment: Das Verb „lieben“ ist doch in beiden Fällen ein transitives – nur eben einmal mit dem Reflexivpronomen als Akkusativ-Ergänzung, oder?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich schon. Man könnte auch "sich waschen" vs. "etw waschen" betrachten.

Comment: Gerade weil Dir aufgefallen ist, dass "sich lieben" "sich selbst lieben" bedeuten kann verstehe ich nicht, wie Du im letzten Absatz dann der mehrdeutigen Version Dein Herz schenkst.

Comment: So ist das halt mit der Sprache. Das ist nicht immer logisch.

Answer (score 2):

Vorab, der [Duden](https://web.archive.org/web/20171011115847/http://www.duden.de:80/rechtschreibung/sich) nennt als Synonym zu *sich* unter anderem *sich gegenseitig*, was beide Aussagen auf etwa ein gleiches Level stellt.

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Rezipr.html) hält fest:

> Reziproke Pronomen drücken eine wechselseitige Beziehung aus. Im Deutschen verwendet man dafür das unveränderliche Pronomen einander.
>
> Oft werden auch die Reflexivpronomen des Plurals verwendet. Zur Verdeutlichung der Wechselseitigkeit kann gegenseitig verwendet werden.
>
> Als falsch gelten die doppelten Formen einander gegenseitig und sich einander:

Die kurze Antwort lautet: Egal, welche Variante du verwendest, du sagst in jedem Fall dasselbe aus. Du kannst gegebenenfalls eine Betonung auf die Gegenseitigkeit legen, was je nach Kontext hilfreich sein kann.

Die ausführliche Diskussion:

**„Sie lieben einander.“ vs. „Sie lieben sich.“ vs. „Sie lieben sich gegenseitig.“**

Auch wenn man schon mal eine Phrase in der Form *[die Liebe] beruht auf Gegenseitigkeit* hört und es nicht unüblich ist, *Sie lieben sich gegenseitig* zu sagen, empfinde ich *gegenseitig* ist hier redundant, da der Teil *Sie lieben sich* dies schon impliziert. Dies gilt übrigens grundsätzlich, nicht nur in diesem Kontext. Die Redundanz, wie einleitend erwähnt, kann aber im Sinne der Hervorhebung bewusst gewählt werden. Nur zweifle ich daran, dass das jedem so bewusst ist.

Es ist richtig, dass der Satz *Sie lieben sich* sowohl *Selbstliebe*, *Eigenliebe* bzw. *Egozentrik* ausdrücken kann, als auch die gegenseitige Liebe, nur ist dies in aller Regel aus dem Kontext zu erkennen. Außerdem ist die Phrase *Sie lieben sich* tendenziell der *gegenseitigen Liebe* vorbehalten, wodurch man eher Wörter wie *Selbstliebe* verwenden würde, wenn man dies vermitteln wollte, oder sonst in irgendeiner Form das Wort *selbst* im Satz unterbringt. Zum Beispiel:

> Sie sind sehr selbstverliebt.

Sucht man im Internet nach *Sie lieben sich,* findet man (fast) ausschließlich Anwendungen im Sinne der gegenseitigen Liebe. Zum Beispiel findet man [ein Gedicht von Heinrich Heine](https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/Gedichte/BdL/Heimk-33.html) oder Artikel in Online-Ausgaben, wie beispielsweise der [Express](https://www.express.de/news/kristen-stewart-und-ihr-regisseur-sie-liebten-sich-schon-in-berlin-5883408).

Auch [Dictionaries](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/Sie%20lieben%20sich.html) übersetzen den Satz als gegenseitige Liebe.

*Sie lieben einander* klingt für mich im ersten Moment formaler oder literarischer. In der Tat finden sich bei einer Googlesuche einige Links unter den ersten Suchergebnissen, die den Verdacht verstärken könnten. Nur ist keine seriöse Quelle dabei, die dies bestätigt. Und zugegeben, bei einem zweiten Blick auf diese Formulierung, klingt sie in der Tat nicht mehr formal.

Beide Varianten *Sie lieben sich* und *Sie lieben einander* kennzeichnen gleichermaßen ein wechselseitiges Verhältnis. Letztlich bin ich noch auf [diesen Link](http://www.dietz-und-daf.de/GD_DkfA/Gramminfo/txt_MI2/Reziproke%20Verben%20Info.pdf) gestoßen, der die einführende Darstellung von canoo.net nochmals bestätigt. Dort heißt es:

> Bei Verben, die sowohl reziprok als auch nicht-reziprok vorkommen, kann man sich oder einander verwenden.

Somit kann man sowohl *einander* als auch *sich* verwenden, um die gegenseitige Liebe auszudrücken. *Gegenseitig*, wie vorhin erwähnt, ist in meinen Augen redundant und daher überflüssig, ist aber auf der anderen Seite auch nicht falsch. Man kann dadurch nochmal die wechselseitige Wirkung hervorheben und betonen. Aus eigener Erfahrung würde ich sagen, es ist aber in dem gegebenen Beispiel unüblich, *gegenseitig* anzuhängen.

Dies gilt natürlich auch, wenn anstatt *sich* ein anderes Reflexivpronomen verwendet wird.

**„Ihr verprügelt einander.“ vs. „Ihr verprügelt euch.“ vs. „Ihr verprügelt euch gegenseitig.“**

Hier gilt im Wesentlichen dasselbe, dennoch denke ich (erneut auf eigene Erfahrungen basierend), dass in diesem Kontext *einander* absolut unüblich ist, und das Anhängen von *gegenseitig* dagegen häufig vorzufinden ist. Spricht man aber nur von *prügeln*, so ist einzig *Sie prügeln sich* richtig.

Unabhängig davon, welches Wort man einsetzt, ist das Anhängen von *gegenseitig* immer seltener als ohne. Zum Beispiel bringt *Sie schlagen sich gegenseitig* wesentlich weniger Google-Suchergebnisse als nur *Sie schlagen sich*.

Das kann daran liegen, dass *gegenseitig* in der Tat optional ist und keine weitere Konnotation impliziert. In manchen Kontexten ist aber der Zusatz *gegenseitig* auch schlicht falsch.

Der Teilsatz *sie treffen sich gegenseitig* ist nur in bestimmten Situationen richtig, zum Beispiel wenn man Trefferpunkte beim *gegenseitig schlagen* meint, nicht aber, wenn man *aufeinandertreffen* meint.

> Vater und Sohn treffen sich heute zum ersten Mal seit 10 Jahren wieder.
>
> Beiden Boxer weisen eine schlechte Deckung auf und treffen sich gegenseitig im Gesicht.

Answer (score 1):

Da keine weiteren linguistischen Erklärungen kommen, hier noch einmal eine aus dem Sprachgefühl: 
"sich" ist in diesem Fall (Plural) mindestens zweideutig. Um es ganz klar zu machen, kann man zwischen "sich selbst" einerseits und "einander"/"sich gegenseitig" andererseits unterscheiden.

Der Unterschied zwischen "einander" und "sich gegenseitig" ist nur eine Nuance, gefühlsmäßig etwa: "einander" drückt eine Einheit aus (Wir lieben einander.), während bei "gegenseitig" getrennte Vorgänge beschrieben werden (Wir waschen uns gegenseitig: Ich wasche dich, dann wäschst du mich.)  Daher würde ein Muttersprachler nie sagen "Wir lieben uns gegenseitig."  "Wir lieben uns" ist wahrscheinlich umgangssprachlich am gebräuchlichsten und wirdauch immer richtig verstanden werden. trotzdem finde ich "Wir lieben einander" noch korrekter. Gleiches gilt für die dritte Person Plural. @Em1: Ich habe noch nicht genügend Reputation, um mit einem Kommentar auf Ihren Kommentar zu antworten, daher habe ich diese Antwort editiert.

Bei "verprügeln" kann man alle drei verwenden, da in der Regel aus dem Zusammenhang klar werden sollte, daß sich die Beteiligten nicht selbst verprügeln.

Comment: Was ist dein Fazit bzgl. der ersten beiden Beispiele? Kann man dort auch alle drei verwenden, oder ist dort das ein oder andere nicht ganz richtig?