# Wie kann man "sich etwas teilen"?

Tags: difference, reflexive

Ich bin verwirrt, wann man einfach "teilen" oder "sich teilen" benutzen sollte.  Auf Englisch bedeutet "teilen" "to share" oder "to divide." Trotzdem sehe ich es manchmal in Verbindung mit "sich" und weiß nicht genau, wann das notwendig ist oder wie die Bedeutung dadurch geändert wird.  Hier sind einige Beispiele von Linguee – es wäre mir genug, dass jemand diese erklärte.

- *Die beiden Kinder haben sich eine Tüte Süßigkeiten geteilt.*  (Ich vermute, dass "sich" da nicht reflexives ist, oder?  Ist es wie "miteinander"?)
- *Ich habe den Kuchen in vier Portionen geteilt.*  (Kann mach "sich" da hinzufügen?)
- *Die Zellen teilten sich schnell und bildeten bald einen Embryo.*  (Die reflexive Bedeutung da ist klar und ganz anders als die oben genannte, oder?)

Bitte korrigieren Sie andere Fehler – ich lerne noch Deutsch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ihre Idee mit *(mit)einander* ist richtig.

Das Verb *teilen* hat im Wesentlichen drei Bedeutungen, wobei ich zwei Bedeutungen zusammenfasse:

1. in Bestandteile zerlegen (engl.: *to divide* / *to split*)
2. a) anderen einen Teil von etwas geben (engl.: *to share*)

   b) mit anderen etwas gemeinsam haben (engl.: *to share*)

#### *Sich* bei Bedeutung 1

Schauen wir uns zunächst die erste Bedeutung an. Hier kann man durch ein Akkusativobjekt angeben, was in Bestandteile zerlegt ist:

> - Die Zelle hat *ihren Kern* / *sich* geteilt.
>
>   <sup>(The cell has divided *its nucleus* / *itself*.)</sup>

Das Reflexivpronomen *[sich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sich#d-1-1)* tritt hier also als Akkusativobjekt auf.

#### *Sich* bei Bedeutung 2

Schauen wir nun auf die zweite Bedeutung. Hier soll es nicht um das Akkusativobjekt gehen, sondern um das Dativobjekt, das ausdrückt, wem ein Teil von etwas gegeben wird:

> - Sie haben Süßigkeiten *mit Thomas* / *mit mir* / *miteinander* geteilt.
>
>   <sup>(They shared sweets *with Thomas* / *with me* / *with each other*.)</sup>

Das Adverb *[miteinander](https://www.dwds.de/wb/miteinander)* kann dazu verwendet werden, um auszudrücken, dass die Süßigkeiten zwischen den einzelnen Kindern wechselseitig ausgetauscht wurden. In dem Adverb steckt das Pronomen *[einander](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einander)*, das das reziproke Verhältnis ausdrückt.

Allerdings wird das *einander* immer häufiger durch *[sich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sich#d-1-2)* ersetzt. Im Beispielsatz

> - Sie haben *sich* Süßigkeiten geteilt.

erkennt man aufgrund der geänderten Struktur noch, was gemeint ist. Doch es gibt Beispiele, wo die Ersetzung von *einander* durch *sich* zu Problemen führt:

> - Sie haben *miteinander* gekämpft.
>
>   <sup>(They fought *with each other*.)</sup>
> - Sie haben *mit sich* gekämpft.
>
>   <sup>(They fought *with each other*. / They struggled [*with themselves*].)</sup>

Im ersten Satz ist durch Verwendung von *miteinander* klar, dass es um einen gegenseitigen Kampf geht. Im zweiten Satz gibt es zwei Bedeutungsmöglichkeiten: entweder geht es um einen gegenseitigen Kampf oder um ein Ringen mit seinen eigenen Gedanken (das heißt, um einen metaphorischen Kampf mit sich selbst).

Früher wurde der Bedeutungsunterschied durch die beiden Pronomen ausgedrückt. Heutzutage liest und hört man jedoch immer häufiger Sätze mit *sich*, wo früher *einander* gestanden hätte. Tatsächlich gilt *einander* heute als [gehoben](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einander) und wird deshalb, um nicht gar ab*gehoben* zu klingen, im normalen Sprachgebrauch vermieden. Gleichwohl empfiehlt [Duden Online](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/sicheinander) in Fällen wie oben, auf *einander* zurückzugreifen, um Klarheit zu schaffen.

Das Thema [*einander* versus *sich*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5306/25241) wurde schon mal auf German StackExchange behandelt.

Comment: Das Reflexivpronomen im Dativ und die Präpositionalphrase mit *mit* sind nicht  austauschbar, denn sie können gemeinsam auftreten: *Wir haben **uns** den Kuchen **mit ihnen** geteilt.*

Comment: @DavidVogt, ist das nicht ein Pleonasmus? Das Weglassen von entweder *uns* oder *mit ihnen* ändert doch nichts an der Aussage. Sonst müsste es ja möglich sein, eines davon auszutauschen, also etwa *„Wir haben **euch** den Keuchen mit **mit ihnen** geteilt“* oder *„Wir haben **uns** den Kuchen **mit ihm** geteilt.“* Das ergibt aber keinen Sinn, oder übersehe ich da etwas?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich *Wir haben euch etw. geteilt* wäre nicht mehr reflexiv. In *Wir haben mit ihm etw. geteilt* vs. *Wir haben **uns** mit ihm etw. geteilt* könnte man überlegen, ob ersteres zunächst nur für den wechselseitigen Austausch zwischen der Gruppe *wir* und *ihm* steht, während zweiteres (*wir uns*) explizit auch den Austausch innerhalb der Gruppe miteinschließt. In vielen Fällen richtet sich der Gebrauch aber wohl eher nach Gewohnheit und Geschmack des Sprechenden als nach dieser potentiellen Bedeutungsunterscheidung.

Comment: Das reflexive Objekt scheint optional zu sein und kann damit von mir aus als überflüssig bezeichnet werden. (Ein Unterschied vielleicht bei Wendungen; für mich ist *ich musste (mir) das Bett mit einer Unbekannten teilen* ohne Dativ anzüglich.) Aber aufgrund der referentiellen Identität mit dem Subjekt bezeichnet es das Agens, während die Präpositionalphrase mit *mit* den Nutznießer bezeichnet.

Comment: Bei *sich etwas mit jemandem teilen* ist "jemand" kein Dativobjekt, wie du schreibst, sondern gar kein Objekt.

Answer (score 3):

Das Verb wird verwirrender, je weiter man darüber nachdenkt :)  Ich vermute, dass das Problem daher kommt, dass das Reflexivpronomen und die freie Angabe eines Benefizienten (Dat) im Plural gleich ausschauen.

Folgende Möglichkeiten fallen mir ein:

1. ***teilen* + Objekt.Akk [+ Präpositionalphrase mit *in* + Akk]**: "divide [into]" oder "share"; ohne *in* nicht eindeutig:

   > Wir haben den Kuchen [in Stücke] geteilt.
2. ***teilen* + Reflexivpronomen.Akk [+ Präpositionalphrase mit *in* + Akk]**: medialer Gebrauch, würde ich sagen (Zellteilung etc.; vgl. *sich waschen*):

   > Wir haben uns [in Gruppen, Zellhaufen, ...] geteilt (= "we split (up) [into groups/cell clusters]")
3. ***teilen* + Objekt.Akk [+ Präpositionalphrase mit *mit*]**: "share with", oder "divide with" (instrumental/komitativ); ohne *mit* wieder nicht eindeutig:

   > Wir haben den Kuchen [mit den Leuten] geteilt (= "we shared the cake [with the people]")

   > Wir haben den Kuchen [mit den Leuten/mit dem Messer] geteilt (= "we divided the cake [together with the people/with the knife]")
4. ***teilen* + (Personalpronomen.Dat, kongruent mit Subjekt) + Objekt.Akk** "share", oder "divide" mit Benefizient:

   > Wir haben uns den Kuchen geteilt (= "we shared the cake", oder: "we divided the cake for us")
5. ***teilen* + Personalpronomen.Dat + Objekt.Akk**  "divide" mit Angabe des Benefizienten

   > Wir haben ihnen den Kuchen geteilt (= "we divided the cake for them")

Die letzten zwei sind die problematischen. Aufgrund des vermutlich häufigeren Gebrauchs und des Mangels der Unterscheidung "share"/"divide" hat Konstruktion wohl die sehr eigenständige Bedeutung gewonnen (vgl. *wir haben [uns] ein Auto gekauft*).

Answer (score 0):

There are many verbs having a preposition for *teilen* which makes it much more precise:

- (sich etwas) **einteilen**: to plan with a resource in advance (food, time, gas)
- (etwas) **aufteilen**: to split something into parts (smaller groups)
- (sich/etwas) **mitteilen**: to share/distribute your own words/opinion
- (etwas) **verteilen**: to spread (money, ads, food)
- (etwas) **austeilen**: to give, unbound to the source (food, punches)
- (etwas) **erteilen**: to give authorization, order, knowledge

With these it might also be easier to not "freely" mix in "sich", as then it almost always makes no sense anymore. From https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/teilen you can see even more verbs. To adapt to your examples:

- Die beiden Kinder haben eine Tüte Süßigkeiten **untereinander aufgeteilt.**
- Ich habe den Kuchen in vier Stücke **aufgeteilt** (er kann **sich** ja nicht selbst aufteilen).

"Die Zellen teilten sich" is a difficult one - I have no better word for the biological doubling process, but "sich" is mandatory here.